# Thick and patterned arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am trying to get an arrow that is thick but not entirely black but has a pattern (e.g., crosshatch). I am not sure how to get this. I have the following that still gives me a black arrow:

```
   \documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}      

   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,fit,positioning,arrows,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tikzset{
   bigbigbox/.style = {minimum width=3.5cm, rectangle},
   bigbox/.style = {draw, rectangle},
   box/.style = {minimum width=2.7cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!20},
   square/.style = {minimum width=15mm,minimum height=15mm}
   }

   \node[square,draw,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (a1) {Map Tasks};
   \node[square,draw,right of=a1,xshift=20mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (a2) {Mapper Input Cache};
   \node[square,draw,below of=a1,yshift=-15mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (a3) {Reduce Tasks};
   \node[square,draw,below of=a2,yshift=-15mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (a4) {Check Fixed Point};

   \draw[-triangle 90, line width=1mm, black,pattern=crosshatch,postaction=        {draw=black,pattern=crosshatch, line width=3mm, shorten >=0.2cm, -}] (a2.west) -- (a1.east);

   \node[bigbox] [fit = (a1) (a4)] (box1){};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Do something like `\draw[pattern=crosshatch] (a2.west) -- (a1.east) -- (a3.east) -- cycle;` to see how `pattern` work (it is a `fill`ing variant and does not affect the `draw`ing). You will need to have an arrow-like area and not just one linear path.  The `single arrow` from the `shapes.arrow` library may come in handy.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the suggestion. As the code shows, I already tried the "pattern=crosshatch" without effect, which is why I am asking. Perhaps I misunderstood your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) states regarding the Pattern Library:

> The package defines patterns for filling areas.

The key word is *filling*.

You used pattern on an path that has (nearly, see below) no area. A `fill` would not be seen either.

My proposed solution uses the `single arrow` *shape* with a pattern:

```
\path let \p1=(a1.east), \p2=(a2.west), \n1={abs(\x2-\x1)} in node[
    draw,
    pattern=crosshatch,
    single arrow,
    rotate=180,
    minimum height=\n1,
    anchor=west,
    at=(a2.west),
    outer xsep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
] {};
```

What does happen here?

- `draw`: We want an outlining border.
- `pattern=crosshatch`
- `single arrow`: This is a short version of `shape=single arrow` and declares the node’s shape.
- `rotate=180`: The natural direction is 0° (right), we turn the arrow around so that it points to the left.
- `minimum height=\n1`: The height (i.e. the length of the arrow) is set to the distance between the `.east` anchor from the left node and the `.west` anchor from the right node. (The `calc` library is used for the `let … in` operators.)
- `anchor=west`: We use the shape’s `.west` anchor (the bottom of the shaft) to place the arrow.
- `at=(a2.west)`: The node’s `.west` anchor (see above) is placed at the `.west` anchor of the right node.
- `outer xsep=-.5\pgflinewidth`: This is a cheat to overlay the shaft’s bottom line to lie exactly on the line from the right node. Comment it out to get:

  [image]

  In my opinion this does not look good.

Coincidentally the default dimensions of the arrow match pretty good your arrow-ed line.
Check the PGF manual’s section 48.5 “Arrow Shapes” to change the appearance of the arrow further.

### Nearly?

Nearly means that the arrow head itself uses drawing but the thick line width overdraws this. In the following example the opacity it set to 50 % to show that the arrow head contains a filling. The corresponding PGF command as used in the `arrows` library is `\pgfusepathqfillstroke`.

#### Code

```
\draw[line width=5mm,opacity=.5,-triangle 90,pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

#### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.arrows,
    positioning,
    patterns,
    calc,
}
\tikzset{
    square/.style={
        minimum width=15mm,
        minimum height=15mm,
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[square,draw,text width=1.5cm,align=center]                          (a1) {Map Tasks};
\node[square,draw,right of=a1,xshift=20mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center]  (a2) {Mapper Input Cache};
\path let \p1=(a1.east), \p2=(a2.west), \n1={abs(\x2-\x1)} in node[
    draw,
    pattern=crosshatch,
    single arrow,
    rotate=180,
    minimum height=\n1,
    anchor=west,
    at=(a2.west),
    outer xsep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very much appreciate this. Obviously this goes way beyond my level of expertise or comfort with tikz. I'll use this.