# Make thick, patterned, rounded corner adjustable arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I want to do a specific type of arrow, patterned like this: [Thick and patterned arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98678/thick-and-patterned-arrows)

Although I need the line to bend twice, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try 'line join=round' as line or global picture option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\newlength\LineWd
\newlength\ArrowWd
\newlength\ArrowHt

\newlength\tmp
\newlength\tmpi

\setlength\LineWd{8pt}

\NewDocumentCommand\HatchUpArrow{O{\LineWd}mO{\x2-\x1}m}{
\begingroup
\setlength\LineWd{#1}
\setlength\ArrowWd{2.5\LineWd}
\pgfmathsetlength{\ArrowHt}{(sqrt(3)*\ArrowWd)/2}
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch]
  let
  \p1=(#4),
  \p2=(#2)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \ifdim\x2>\x1\relax
      \setlength\tmp{0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{0.5\ArrowWd}
    \else
      \setlength\tmp{-0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{-0.5\ArrowWd}
    \fi
    }
  {[rounded corners=0.5\LineWd]
  ([xshift=\tmp]\p2) -- 
  ++(0pt,{abs(#3)}) coordinate (aux1) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p1|-aux1)} coordinate (aux2) --
  ([shift={(-\tmp,\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --  
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) -- 
  (\p1) -- 
  ([shift={(\tmpi,\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) --
  ([shift={(2\tmp,-\LineWd)}]aux2) --
  ++([xshift=-2\tmp]\x2-\x1,0pt) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p2); 
\endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\HatchDownArrow{O{\LineWd}mO{\x2-\x1}m}{
\begingroup
\setlength\LineWd{#1}
\setlength\ArrowWd{2.5\LineWd}
\pgfmathsetlength{\ArrowHt}{(sqrt(3)*\ArrowWd)/2}
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch]
  let
  \p1=(#4),
  \p2=(#2)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \ifdim\x2>\x1\relax
      \setlength\tmp{0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{0.5\ArrowWd}
    \else
      \setlength\tmp{-0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{-0.5\ArrowWd}
    \fi
    }
  {[rounded corners=0.5\LineWd]
  ([xshift=\tmp]\p2) -- 
  ++(0pt,{-abs(#3)}) coordinate (aux1) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p1|-aux1)} coordinate (aux2) --
  ([shift={(-\tmp,-\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --  
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) -- 
  (\p1) -- 
  ([shift={(\tmpi,-\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) --
  ([shift={(2\tmp,\LineWd)}]aux2) --
  ++([xshift=-2\tmp]\x2-\x1,0pt) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p2); 
\endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\HatchLeftArrow{O{\LineWd}mO{\y1-\y2}m}{
\begingroup
\setlength\LineWd{#1}
\setlength\ArrowWd{2.5\LineWd}
\pgfmathsetlength{\ArrowHt}{(sqrt(3)*\ArrowWd)/2}
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch]
  let
  \p1=(#4),
  \p2=(#2)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \ifdim\y2>\y1\relax
      \setlength\tmp{0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{0.5\ArrowWd}
    \else
      \setlength\tmp{-0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{-0.5\ArrowWd}
    \fi
    }
  {[rounded corners=0.5\LineWd]
  ([yshift=\tmp]\p2) -- 
  ++({-abs(#3)},0pt) coordinate (aux1) --
  ([yshift=-\tmp]\p1-|aux1)} coordinate (aux2) --
  ([shift={(-\ArrowHt,-\tmp)}]\p1) --  
  ++(0pt,\tmp-\tmpi) -- 
  (\p1) -- 
  ([shift={(-\ArrowHt,\tmpi)}]\p1) --
  ++(0pt,\tmp-\tmpi) --
  ([shift={(\LineWd,2\tmp)}]aux2) --
  ([shift={(\LineWd,-2\tmp)}]aux1) --
  ([yshift=-\tmp]\p2); 
\endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\HatchRightArrow{O{\LineWd}mO{\y2-\y1}m}{
\begingroup
\setlength\LineWd{#1}
\setlength\ArrowWd{2.5\LineWd}
\pgfmathsetlength{\ArrowHt}{(sqrt(3)*\ArrowWd)/2}
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch]
  let
  \p1=(#4),
  \p2=(#2)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \ifdim\y2>\y1\relax
      \setlength\tmp{0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{0.5\ArrowWd}
    \else
      \setlength\tmp{-0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{-0.5\ArrowWd}
    \fi
    }
  {[rounded corners=0.5\LineWd]
  ([yshift=\tmp]\p2) -- 
  ++({abs(#3)},0pt) coordinate (aux1) --
  ([yshift=-\tmp]\p1-|aux1)} coordinate (aux2) --
  ([shift={(\ArrowHt,-\tmp)}]\p1) --  
  ++(0pt,\tmp-\tmpi) -- 
  (\p1) -- 
  ([shift={(\ArrowHt,\tmpi)}]\p1) --
  ++(0pt,\tmp-\tmpi) --
  ([shift={(-\LineWd,2\tmp)}]aux2) --
  ([shift={(-\LineWd,-2\tmp)}]aux1) --
  ([yshift=-\tmp]\p2); 
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
myblock/.style={draw,minimum size=2cm}
]
\node[myblock] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[myblock] (B) at (3,0) {B};
\HatchUpArrow{A.north}{B.north}
\HatchDownArrow{A.south}[30pt]{B.south}

\node[myblock] (C) at (6,0) {C};
\node[myblock] (D) at (9,2) {D};
\HatchUpArrow[20pt]{D.north}[30pt]{C.north}
\HatchDownArrow[6pt]{[xshift=-15pt]C.south east}[20pt]{[xshift=15pt]D.south west}

\node[myblock] (G) at (2,-4) {G};
\node[myblock] (H) at (2,-7) {H};
\HatchLeftArrow[15pt]{H.west}{G.west}
\HatchRightArrow{G.east}[1.5cm]{H.east}

\node[myblock] (I) at (8,-4) {I};
\node[myblock] (J) at (11,-6) {J};
\HatchLeftArrow{I.west}[1cm]{J.west}
\HatchRightArrow{I.east}[4cm]{J.east}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The main commands:

- `\HatchUpArrow[<width>]{<start coordinate>}[<length>]{<end coordinate>}`
- `\HatchDownArrow[<width>]{<start coordinate>}[<length>]{<end coordinate>}`
- `\HatchLeftArrow[<width>]{<start coordinate>}[<length>]{<end coordinate>}`
- `\HatchRightArrow[<width>]{<start coordinate>}[<length>]{<end coordinate>}`

Comment: Thank you very much Gonzalo, your promptness to answer tex related issues is really astonishing!

Comment: @DinisNunes You're welcome. Glad I could help! Let me know if you need "Left" and "Right" variants of the arrow.

Comment: I just need the up version really, although I wanted to be able to control the arrow tip shape, how can I do that?

Comment: @DinisNunes Is not that easy. What would you like to control about the arrow tip?

Comment: I would like it to be a 60º triangle. Also, I can't seem to figure it out how to make a simple arrow going from north to south with no hatch.

Comment: @DinisNunes I have to leave now, but in some hours I'll make the adjustments for the  60º arrow. I don't understand the second part of your comment. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I wanted to do a straight arrow, no corners, leaving south of a node to north of another node just below it, I thought I could do it with the instructions from the other thread that I've linked, but I'm not being successful.

Comment: @DinisNunes I updated my answer with a 60º triangle tip arrow. Regarding the other arrow question, is hard to tell what is going on without seeing the code you are using. I'd suggest you to open a fresh new question providing there a simple document showing your settings and the problem you mentioned.