# Downward patterned arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

Following instructions from this thread, [Thick and patterned arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98678/thick-and-patterned-arrows), I've managed to replicate the arrow, but pointing downward. However, I'm also using another very similar arrow, code here -[Make thick, patterned, rounded corner adjustable arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265865/make-thick-patterned-rounded-corner-adjustable-arrow/) - and I get mismatching arrow tips.

[image]

Any way to make the arrow on the left have the same tip as the one on the right?

Code for the left arrow:

```
\path let \p1=(a3.south), \p2=(a4.north), \n1={abs(\x2-\x1)} in node[
draw,
pattern=crosshatch,
single arrow,
rotate=-90,
minimum height=1.5cm,
anchor=south,
at=(a3.south),
outer xsep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
] {};
```

Comment: And code for right arrows? It seems that in its definition of arrow head is different as it is for left one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow on the left has a 60 degree arrow tip, so you can use `single arrow tip angle=60` for the arrow on the right. You could also use `single arrow head extend=<length>` to control the height of the arrow tip, if required.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.arrows,
    positioning,
    patterns,
    calc,
}
\tikzset{
    square/.style={
        minimum width=15mm,
        minimum height=15mm,
    },
}

\newlength\LineWd
\newlength\ArrowWd
\newlength\ArrowHt

\newlength\tmp
\newlength\tmpi

\setlength\LineWd{8pt}

\NewDocumentCommand\HatchUpArrow{O{\LineWd}mO{\x2-\x1}m}{
\begingroup
\setlength\LineWd{#1}
\setlength\ArrowWd{2.5\LineWd}
\pgfmathsetlength{\ArrowHt}{(sqrt(3)*\ArrowWd)/2}
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch]
  let
  \p1=(#4),
  \p2=(#2)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \ifdim\x2>\x1\relax
      \setlength\tmp{0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{0.5\ArrowWd}
    \else
      \setlength\tmp{-0.5\LineWd}
      \setlength\tmpi{-0.5\ArrowWd}
    \fi
    }
  {[rounded corners=0.5\LineWd]
  ([xshift=\tmp]\p2) -- 
  ++(0pt,{abs(#3)}) coordinate (aux1) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p1|-aux1)} coordinate (aux2) --
  ([shift={(-\tmp,\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --  
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) -- 
  (\p1) -- 
  ([shift={(\tmpi,\ArrowHt)}]\p1) --
  ++(\tmp-\tmpi,0pt) --
  ([shift={(2\tmp,-\LineWd)}]aux2) --
  ++([xshift=-2\tmp]\x2-\x1,0pt) --
  ([xshift=-\tmp]\p2); 
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[square,draw,text width=1.5cm,align=center]
  (a1) {Map Tasks};
\node[square,draw,below=2cm of a1,text width=1.5cm,align=center]  
  (a2) {Mapper Input Cache};
\node[square,draw,right=of a2,text width=1.5cm,align=center]  
  (a3) {Test a};
\path let \p1=(a1.south), \p2=(a2.north), \n1={abs(\y2-\y1)} in node[
    draw,
    pattern=crosshatch,
    single arrow,
    rotate=270,
    minimum height=\n1,
    anchor=west,
    at=(a1.250),
    outer xsep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
    single arrow tip angle=60,
    single arrow head extend=4pt,
] {};
\HatchUpArrow[6pt]{a3.north}[30pt]{a2.60}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]