# Path decoration disappears when adding a pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pattern

I would like to fill the area under a curve with a pattern. The curve has arrows as decoration. Filling the area with a color works fine.
[image: fill]

If I replace the `fill` with a `pattern` the arrow decorations disappear.
[image: pattern]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top = true,
        axis lines = center,
        ticks = none,
        enlargelimits,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    ]
        \addplot[
            pattern = north west lines,
%           fill = yellow,
            postaction = {decorate},
            decoration = {
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}},
                mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{stealth}}
            },
            domain = 0:8,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {16-(x-4)^2}
            \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the arrows from being covered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `postaction` for the pattern.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top = true,
        axis lines = center,
        ticks = none,
        enlargelimits,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    ]
        \addplot[
            postaction={pattern = north west lines},
            postaction = {decorate},
            decoration = {
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}},
                mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{stealth}}
            },
            domain = 0:8,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {16-(x-4)^2}
            \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are viewer-dependent artifacts, using `patterns.meta` very often fixes them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top = true,
        axis lines = center,
        ticks = none,
        enlargelimits,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    ]
        \addplot[
            postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}},
            postaction = {decorate},
            decoration = {
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}},
                mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{stealth}}
            },
            domain = 0:8,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {16-(x-4)^2}
            \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was almost at that point, but I've put `pattern` and `decorate` in the same `postaction = {pattern = north west lines, decorate}` which didn't work.

Comment: In the image you can see an undesired white vertical line below the arrow at `pos=0.6`. Could you fix it with that method?

Comment: @SebastiánV.Romero Ot course. These are viewer-dependent artifacts. For the viewers I am familiar with there are very likely to go away if one does the pattern with `patterns.meta`. Please note that even in the first code there is no problem with Acrobat Reader, at least in theory.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer! @Schrödinger'scat

Answer (score 4):

Reading what was said [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98678/thick-and-patterned-arrows), you need to delimit an area before adding a pattern. Just put in your code `fill=white` before your pattern. Hope it works as you want!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top = true,
        axis lines = center,
        ticks = none,
        enlargelimits,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    ]
        \addplot[
            fill = white,
            pattern = north west lines,
            postaction = {decorate},
            decoration = {
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}},
                mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{stealth}}
            },
            domain = 0:8,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {16-(x-4)^2}
            \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for you solution! It works.

Comment: You're welcome! :D `@luki`